# How to access a table in a personal geodatabase using C#

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-10.1

I've a personal geodatabase which has some shape files included. To get a "complex" relation I've created a single table which will be have 1:1 or 1:N references which the different shape files (atm. 3).

Now I want to know how I can:

1. access the table in the personal geodatabase,
2. add new entries to this table,
3. remove/modify existing entries

using C#. Does anybody done this before and can help me to solve this question?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it a normal ITable? What is the exact problem you are facing now?

Comment: I've created the table unsing ArcCatalog and I dont know how I can handle and access this tavble in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with personal geodatabase, this code should work for you. For other kind of workspace, to open the workspace, you need different type of workspace factory.

```
void DoTableProcessing(string workspacePath)
{
    IWorkspace workspace = OpenWorkspace(workspacePath);
    List<ITable> tables = GetTables(workspace);
    //Do process
}

List<ITable> GetTables(IWorkspace workspace)
{
    var enumDataset = workspace.Datasets[esriDatasetType.esriDTTable];
    var datasets = new List<ITable>();
    IDataset dataset;
    while ((dataset = enumDataset.Next()) != null)
        datasets.Add(dataset as ITable);
    return datasets;
}

IWorkspace OpenWorkspace(string workspacePath)
{
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass();
    return workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(path, 0);
}
```

To do work with ITable you may see [ITable interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000089m000000). You can do search, select, modify, add rows through this interface.

Comment: This link is for ArcObjects. What library I should install before using the code? Because they are in red color